# Is it ok for a reference engine to write data into .aux file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm writing a Lua citation processor for the Citation Style Language (CSL) located at https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua. It needs torun as a external executive for LaTeX engines other than LuaTeX. I have a question about the design of the workflow: Is
it safe to write the output information directly into `.aux` file?

The traditional BibTeX workflow usually requires three runs of LaTeX engine to make sure the citation labels are correct. In the first pass, the `\citation`, `\bibstyle`, and `\bibdata` commands are written to `.aux` file. Then BibTeX reads the `.aux` file and generates `thebibliography` environment with `\bibitem`s into `.bbl`. In the second pass, LaTeX reads the `.bbl` file and each `\bibitem` command writes `\bibcite` with the citation labels into `.aux`. It is because in some styles the citation labels are reassigned according to their order in bibliography (e.g., `plain.bst`). In the final run, LaTeX loads `.aux` and output the correct citations.

It will save one pass of LaTeX engine if the reference processor directly writes the citation labels into `.aux` file and removes the burden of the second run in the BibTeX workflow. But I'm not sure if it has any side effects.

Comment: Cool question and cool project! If you want your project to be a drop-in replacement for BibTeX in terms of `thebibliography`+`.bbl`+`.aux`, I think it is safer not to write to the `.aux` directly. While for the 'usual setup' you would save some compilation steps, you would deprive LaTeX code of a way to interfere with the generation of the labels, which might come in handy in certain situations: https://gist.github.com/moewew/f49e27377651365e1ab32cf73ce40095.

Comment: I'd like to second the compliment here. Cool project indeed! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the citation processor is intended to be a drop-in replacement for BibTeX in terms of bibliography and citation implementation on the LaTeX side (`.bbl` file with `thebibliography`), I would not have the processor write `\bibcite`s to the `.aux` file directly just to save a LaTeX run.

In the vast majority of setups these `.aux` entries would probably be fine, but this method deprives the LaTeX side of things of a means to manipulate the citation labels on the fly, something that may come in handy in some situations, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibtopicprefix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-A.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-B.bib}
@book{belk,
  author    = {Bertranda Belk},
  title     = {A Theory on Other Sauruses},
  year      = {1973},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{elk,belk}.

\begin{btSect}{\jobname-A}
\renewcommand{\bibprefix}{A}
\btPrintAll
\end{btSect}

\begin{btSect}{\jobname-B}
\renewcommand{\bibprefix}{B}
\btPrintAll
\end{btSect}
\end{document}
```

In this example the prefix is not and need not be exposed to BibTeX via any of the `.aux` files (BibTeX wouldn't have an interface to deal with it anyway). The prefix is added purely on the LaTeX side.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the bibtopicprefix package. Actually CSL has more strict control over the format of citation and references. For example, the whole label `[1-3]` including the surrounding brackets is generated by the citeproc engine so I suppose it's impossible to make CSL compatible with bibtopicprefix.

Comment: @ZepingLee In case you need control over the citations like that, the CSL processor is probably not a simple drop-in replacement for BibTeX or there is an additional component to the CSL implementation on the LaTeX side. In that case the question is if and how you need to use `\bibcite` at all. (`biblatex` for example completely reimplements citations and the bibliography to have more control over the output and does not work with `\bibcite`.) ...

Comment: ... Still in that case I would find it odd to have a "BibTeX replacement" write to the `.aux` file. I'd probably look into dedicated new file or into something like loading the `.bbl` earlier a la `biblatex`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The term "a BibTeX replacement" is not accurate and I'll change the description. Actually I didn't realize their difference when writing the README until I implemented most of the CSL features.